# Чем отслеживать открытие новых вкладок chrome и по условию закрывать?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать, в каком направлении копать:

Есть сайт. С весьма изуверски реализованным открытием страниц (кликаешь на ссылку, там переадресация, и в итоге открывшаяся страница имеет совершенно другой адрес) и кучей вариантов попасть на одну и ту же страницу.

Хочу накатать себе такую штуку, которая будет делать такой алгоритм:

1. Отслеживаю открытия новых вкладок;
2. Дожидаюсь загрузки вкладки (все переадресации и.т.п.);
3. Проверяю адрес загрузившейся страницы по бд;
4. Если адрес уже есть в бд - закрываю вкладку.

Вроде слышал чего то про Selenium, но не уверен может ли он такое? А в многоподключение и многопоточность (если я открою 2ю вкладку до того как 1я загрузится)? Или есть другие инструменты?

И, собственно, если Селениум то где про него лучше почитать про актуальные версии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо просто отслеживать открытие вкладки, то subprocess и команда tasklist тебе в помощь.

```
mas_not_formated = [line.decode('cp866', 'ignore') for line in Popen('tasklist', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()]
mas_not_formated = [value for value in mas_not_formated if len(value.split()) != 0]
mas = [i.split()[1] for i in mas_not_formated]
```

И проверяешь в цикле, если нету в изначальном, тогда действие, однако в случае с твоей задачей, тебе необходим Selenium.

Comment: Так. А теперь мне надо вспомнить, что же я такое ваял 9 месяцев назад, что родилось это.
В любом случае, спасибо за совет, плюсик и галочка улетели =)